# Julia is not recognizing Peaks package function

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (julia language with VS Code) and when I run the following code:

```
using Peaks

v = [3 2 1 2 3]
min = argminima(v,1)
```

It returns me an error:

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: argminima not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ Untitled-2:4
```

I already installed the Peaks package. What could be happening? Any suggestion?

Comment: Try `] update Peaks`?

Comment: If updating doesn't help, please do a `] status Peaks` and report back the version it returns. It seems likely it's stuck in some old version because of compatibility with something else. Confirming whether that's the case will help solve it.

Comment: I tried updating and it still does the same. ```] status Peaks``` returns ```Status ~/.julia/environments/v1.8/Project.toml
   [18e31ff7] Peaks v0.4.0```.

Comment: Did you restart REPL after updating?

Answer (score 0):

Note that `v` should be a column vector [1,2,3] not a 2D row vector [1 2 3].

```
julia> using Peaks

julia> v = [3, 2, 1, 2, 3]
5-element Vector{Int64}:
 3
 2
 1
 2
 3

julia> min = argminima(v)
1-element Vector{Int64}:
 3
```

```bash
(@Temp) pkg> st
Status `~/.julia/environments/Temp/Project.toml`
  [18e31ff7] Peaks v0.4.0
```